# SQL Server : how to find ids where columns have different values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
Column1 Column2
---------------
1       1
1       2
1       3
1       4
2       1
2       1
2       1
2       1
```

In `column1` one there are 2 different ids, in `column2` there are different values for each id from `column1`.

How can I get the id from `column1` where not all ids from `column2` are the same? So in this instance the output should be 1 - because they have all different values in column2, where id from column1 has all 1's in column2

Answer (score 2):

Just use `group by` and `having`:

```
select column1
from table t
group by column1
having min(column2) <> max(column2);
```

Note:  you could also use `count(distinct)`, but that has more overhead than `min()` and `max()`.

Similar logic can be used if the second column could be `NULL`.  That doesn't appear in the sample data so it doesn't seem worth including it in the logic unless the OP specifically says this is a possibility.

Comment: If column2 is ever null this approach will not work.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
select Column1
from yourTable 
group by Column1
having count(DISTINCT column2) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would think something like this should do the job:

```
SELECT t.column1 FROM table t
GROUP BY t.column1
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.column2) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach will handle the case where a null is an acceptable value in column2.

```
select column1
from
(
select distinct column1, column2
from yourTable
) t
group by column1
having count(*) > 1
```